# Unable to query MySQL "Error in querying Error"

Tags: mysql, node.js, next.js

I have a next(v14) API endpoint called /events which queries MySQL DB and sends the data as a JSON back to the client. But for some unknown reason, I am getting this error below
[image: Digital Ocean Server error]

This error only appears in the production version and not locally (P.S. already checked, all the envs are set properly).

the function for querying the db is as follows:

```
import mysql from "mysql2";

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: 25060,
    user     : process.env.DB_USER,
    password : process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database : process.env.DB_DATABASE
});
export const connectDB = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        connection.connect((err) => {
            if (err) 
                reject(err.message);
            else
                resolve();
        });
    })
}

export const queryDB = (queryStr) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        connection.query(queryStr, (err, res) => {
            if (err) 
                reject(err);
            resolve(res);
        })
    })
}

export const disconnectDB = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        connection.end((err) => {
            if (err) 
                reject(err.message);
            else
                resolve();
        });
    })
}
```

and I am calling them in this way

```
export async function GET(){
await connectDB();
const query = `SELECT * FROM Events`
const results = await queryDB(query);
await disconnectDB();

return NextResponse.json({results});
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Print oit the underlying error messgage, not just error in querying and you will know what has gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The issue in the above code was not because of nextjs or any framework/platform based. It was the way I was calling the functions.

1. connectDB() --> function that connects with the MySQL server (a **handshake between SQL server and API server**)
2. queryDB() --> function that queries the connected SQL server
3. disconnectDB() --> function that closes the connection.

One thing I noticed was that the **error did not happen for the first API request it only occurred for the following requests** that were made.
And the reason for that was that for the follow-up requests, once the connection was closed by calling disconnectDB(), I was not opening it again, instead I was connecting with the already closed MySQL connection.

I added the mysql.createConnection as a part of these function calls and the error was resolved.

Here is the modified function

```
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : process.env.DB_HOST,
        port: 25060,
        user     : process.env.DB_USER,
        password : process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
        database : process.env.DB_DATABASE
    });

    await connectDB(connection);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        connection.query(queryStr, (err, res) => {
            connection.end((endErr) => {
                if (endErr) {
                    console.log("IN END DB",endErr.message, endErr.name, endErr);
                    reject("WHILE CLOSING CONNECTION--> ",endErr.message);
                }
                if (err) {
                    console.log("IN QUERY DB",err.message, err.name, err);
                    reject("WHILE QUERYING DB--> ",err.message);
                }
                resolve(res);
            });
        })
    })
```